# Instagram realtime api https

Tags: api, https, instagram

I'm coding an app in PHP and I've had issues starting a tag subscription when I don't use HTTPS, I've tested both ways and would prefer to use HTTP if possible.

Has anyone else run into this and know of a solution?

Their documentation doesn't show the need for https.  When I use HTTP I get the error

> Unable to reach callback URL "http://...

Comment: Why do you prefer http over https ?  Are you afraid of the cpu overload ?

Comment: @Shiva the website chicagogram.herokuapp.com use http but do *https* calls to instagram

Comment: @Tom I would prefer http over https because I'm using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk and installing and SSL cert is a pain in the bug.  Right now for SSL I'm using Cloudflare which gives me a free certificate.

Comment: @Tom - Didn't realize that. How did you find that out? Is it client-side JS?

Comment: As far as code goes, I'm using this base for their function __apiCall(){} 

https://github.com/ianckc/CodeIgniter-Instagram-Library/blob/master/application/libraries/Instagram_api.php and passing parameters as an array.

Comment: @RewardsFuel you don't need https in your website to make an https call (The opposite is not true : from an https website you can't make an ajax call to an http website)

Comment: @tom This is all happening server side.  I successfully post the variables to their service but get a 400 error "couldn't reach callback page"  that changes when I use https.

Comment: I rebuilt the function __apiCall and all seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

My issue wasn't https vs http.  It was my function that curls the post data.  I rebuilt it and it works now.

A note for future people trying to use the Realtime API it returns zero data about the Instagram post which I find odd, why note include a post id at the very least.  All it currently does is ping your server with data about your subscription effected.  Its also worth noting to see that data you have to use this command in PHP

$igdata = file_get_contents("php://input");